# explode function in java as in PHP

Tags: java, string, split

I have a variable in java, which is like this `I+am+good+boy` I want to get seperate them on the basis of `+` , in `PHP` I can use explode which is very handy, is there any function in java?I saw the `split()` function definition but that was not helpful.as it take regular expression.
Any help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options as I know :

```
    String text = "I+am+good+boy";
    System.out.println("Using Tokenizer : ");
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(text, "+");
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
        System.out.println(" Token = " + token);
    }

    System.out.println("\n Using Split :");
    String [] array = text.split("\\+");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
```

Comment: I think you are printing the tokenizer.countTokens() after the while loop. If you need the count of tokens, you need to print it before while loop (after creating the tokenizer object).                       Also you need to be careful about \\ inside the split() method. If given without it, it gives an error. If you facing the issue yet, you can paste your code here so that I can get a clear understanding of the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 3):

Use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) in regards to explode.

An example of use:

Explode :

```
String[] explode = "I+am+a+good+boy".split("+");
```

And you can reverse this like so (or "implode" it):

```
String implode = StringUtils.join(explode[], " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
String str = "I+am+a+good+boy";
String[] array = str.split("\\+");
```

you will get "I", "am", "a", "good", "boy" strings in the array. And you can access them as

```
String firstElem = array[0];
```

In the `firstElem` string you will get "I" as result.
The `\\` before `+` because `split()` takes regular expressions (`regex`) as argument and `regex` has special meaning for a `+`. It means one or more copies of the string trailing the `+`.
So, if you want to get literal `+` sign, then you have to use escape char `\\`.

Comment: that didn't worked as the program crashes when i try to use value of array[0]

Comment: Sorry, I tried myself and solved that, please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use split and escape the regex - either by hand or using the `Pattern.quote()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "I+am+a+good+boy";
String[] pieces = str.split("+")
```

Now you can use `pieces[0]`, `pieces[1]` and so on.

More Info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29